# Spring не может найти в проекте репозиторий

Tags: java, строки, repository, bean

При недавней загрузки приложения из Idea стала вылетать ошибка, хотя раньше было все в порядке и при деплое на heroku все запускается нормально.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in com.melky.bot.vk.handlers.CallbackAPIHandler required a bean of type 'com.melky.bot.vk.repos.ElementToDoListRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.melky.bot.vk.repos.ElementToDoListRepo' in your configuration.
```

Сам код, где используются репозитории

```
@Component
public class CallbackAPIHandler {

    private VKBot vkBot;
    private Weather weather;
    private KeyboardHandler keyboardHandler;
    @Value("${vk.confCode}")
    private String confirmationCode;
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    private ElementToDoListRepo elementRepo;


    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private TransportClient transportClient;
    private VkApiClient vk;
    private GroupActor groupActor;

    public CallbackAPIHandler(@Lazy VKBot vkBot, Weather weather, KeyboardHandler keyboardHandler, UserRepo userRepo, ElementToDoListRepo elementRepo) {
        this.vkBot = vkBot;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.keyboardHandler = keyboardHandler;
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.elementRepo = elementRepo;
    }

   //Много не нужного кода
}
```

Сами репозитории:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ElementToDoListRepo extends CrudRepository<ElementToDoList, Long> {
}
```

Решения еще не нашел, аннотации @EnableJpaRepositories не помогли.

Comment: я обычно указываю путь к репозиториям с помощью аннотации на классе конфигурации моего датасорса примерно так @EnableJpaRepositories("package.name") и никаких проблем

Comment: @Дмитрий я использовал аннотацию EnableJpaRepositories,но тут уже лезет другая ошибка: 
`Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.`

Comment: это уже другая проблема. в вашем проекте их может быть сотня. может проще сделать по образцу или почитать тех документацию, чем угадывать? я не вижу ваш код и не могу угадать, какие потенциальные проблемы могут возникнуть. выгрузите его, к примеру, на гит, дайте ссылку, тогда можно глянуть

Comment: @Дмитрий Да без проблем https://github.com/MelkyEA/PresentResumeBot Проблема в том, что я несколько месяцев не запускал код, а когда запустил, начала лезть эта ошибка

Comment: у вас проблема с созданем бина com.melky.bot.telegram.Bot, который в контроллере вы пытаетесь создать с помощью спринга через конструктор, при этом аннотацию,которая укажет спрингу, что это бин, добавит забыли. мало того , бин с именем "bot" уже существует, поэтому придется указать имя бина для класса com.melky.bot.telegram.Bot: @Service("telegramBot")

Comment: @Дмитрий бин создается в конфигурационном файле com.melky.bot.telegram.config, и он же используется везде

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. Репозиторий поднимает бин с именем `elementToDoListRepo`, а вы пытаетесь инъектить `elementRepo`, которого нет.

Или переименуйте переменную в `elementToDoListRepo`, или используйте `Qualifier`.

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("elementRepo")
public interface ElementToDoListRepo extends CrudRepository<ElementToDoList, Long> {
}
```

[Изучить вопрос подробней](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/auto-wire-by-name.html)

Comment: Добавил, но ошибка не исчезла. Да и тем более с userRepo точно такая же ошибка, а значит проблема не в названии. К тому же на хостинге все запускается и работает. Возможно, есть проблема в моей idea, хотя все импорты и аннотации прописаны и расставлены правильно.